# Consume Json in Python Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to consume data from API which is in the following format. Where `count` can be more than one -

```
{u'count': 1, u'previous': None, u'results': [{u'url': u'http://127.0.0.1:8000/offapp/cities/', u'city_name': u'Kolkata', u'id': 1}], u'next': None}
```

I am using the following method to consume json -

`views.py`

```
def employee(request):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/offapp/cities/').json()
     context = RequestContext(request, {
    'cities': data.results,
})
return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

`template.py`

```
{% for city in cities %}
 <a href="{% url 'next_view_name' city.id %}"><p>{{city.city_name}}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
```

But django can't seem to resolve the name or id and gives the error -

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'city_name'
```

What is the correct way to use this data? I want to be able to use all the data in `results` of json in my template and use id to reverse match and go to the next view using id.

Comment: Can you give an eg. output of `data.city`

Comment: Can you edit your question to post full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: Look like `'cities': data.city` should be `'cities': data.results`

Comment: @JosepValls Yeah sorry.Edited it now.But even that gives the same error `AttributeError at /
dict' object has no attribute 'results'`

Comment: What about `data['results']` instead?

Comment: @YashMehrotra Sorry it was data.results

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I dont get any error on using `data['results']` but I get a blank template and in the python shell when I use                                        `list=data['results']     list.id` I again get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used requests json but looking at the documentation you should be using it as a dictionary as the regular json module.
In your code use `'cities': data['results']` and then in your template use `city.city_name`.

Django templates use dot lookups: when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries a dictionary lookup.

Comment: Sorry, using `city['city_name']` instead of `city.city_name` just gives me the following error -  `Could not parse the remainder: '['city_name']' from 'city['city_name']'`

Comment: I checked and in Django templates seems like you can actually use city.city_name. Did you try that already?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `'city_name'` is a property of `data.results[0]`, not `data.city`. Sorry I can't test the `requests.get(url).json()`, so it may need to be `data['results'][0]`

Comment: But that would only get me the name. What about id? I'd have to run several statements everytime I want a property